# A linear basis compatible with a family of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Let $V$ be a vector space. We say that its basis $B$ is compatible with a family of subspaces $\mathcal{W}$ if $B ∩ W$ is a basis of $W$ for every $W ∈ \mathcal{W}$.

I'd like to know for which spaces and families of subspaces such basis exists. I wonder if this is a standard question with well-known answer.

Some positive cases:

- $|\mathcal{W}| ≤ 2$ (not every $\mathcal{W}$ of size 3 works),
- $\mathcal{W}$ well-ordered by $⊆$,
- $\mathcal{W}$ well-ordered by $⊇$ in a countably dimensional space.